# domain adding a dot in between

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I used to see urls in the presentation of:-

- test.a-normal-domain.com
- demo.another-domain.com

I tried to search these domains in godaddy, but it always say the domain format is incorrect. Then I predict, the actual registered domains are "a-normal-domain.com" and "another-domain.com".

what configuration we have to do in order to produce the test. and demo. appearance in the url so that it will point to the desired web folder for users' browsing? Thanks.

Comment: go to your cpanel and create a subdomain...

Comment: It is incorrect name. "test" and "demo" you write above is subdomain. You need to purchase a-normal-domain.com, then you will be able to create subdomain called test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

referring  to your example `demo.another-domain.com`...

`demo` is a subdomain. once you purchase `another-domain.com` you can add as many subdomains as you want from cpanel. `demo.another-domain.com`, `demo2.another-domain.com`, `demo3.another-domain.com` would all be subdomains of `another-domain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your provider etc.

For some you have to actually tell them you want to register a subdomain, others will only need a "demo" folder under "another-domain.com" to be used as subdomain.

I think it's best to check out your providers FAQ.

If you want to use .htaccess you should put a "demo" folder under "another-domain-com" and then tell all requests to "demo.another-domain.com" to access the folder "demo" like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   ^demo\.another-domain\.com$
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI} !/demo/
RewriteRule   (.*)           /demo/$1 [L]
```